# Why Li is not added as contact by ion implantation method in p type HPGe detector?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, gamma-rays

n+ contact of p type Ge is ~700µm thick compared to p+ contact of n type Ge only ~0.3µm. The process of adding the contact is different. n+ contact Li is added by diffusion process but p+ contact B is added by ion implantation technique. In diffusion we can get only thick contact but in ion implantation we can achieve thin contact, Fine. With a thin (~0.3µm) Li ion implantation, low energy efficiency of p type HPGe detector can be on par with n type HPGe detector (as per the attached fig).

Why Li is also not added as contact by ion implantation method? Is it a mandatory requirement of having thick (~700µm) n+ contact or only due to technology used for doping, we are getting thick (~700µm) contact?

Comment: Well, why do you want a thick "contact" layer in a gamma detector? What does the device look like in operation under high reverse bias? Why do you think that it is a n+ region through the device? You are correct, if the only question was getting a n+ surface region, ion implantation would be the way to go. So, why is that not the way to go?

Comment: Sir can i hv ur email id pl. I require it to discuss in detail.

Comment: I would suggest starting with https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0146641007000828 and the references therein. And, no, I'm not giving out my email.

Comment: Fine Sir. I have again read the article.  I have not got the answer.                                                                  Whether the reason is as follows? Predominantly HPGe is p type. So compensation of large p type impurity requires more n+ contact. (700um) But n type Ge is made by doping of excess addition of n type impurity in p type HPGe. So n type impurity addition always slightly excess of p type impurity. Hence, slight excess n type impurity in n type HPGe requires, p+ contact with very less thickness. (0.3um)

Comment: Dear Sir, if you have answer pl reply without asking further questions. I dont know the answer hence only I am asking Q. If if u have no answer, I shall assume this Q have no answer. No other person is replying to this question any way.